# Functions score returns same score for all documents

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am using functions score with sampler aggregation to match last visited documents.

**ES Query**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "replace", // we need to replace document score with the result of the functions,
      "query": {
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": { // return `lastvisited` value as score
            "field": "visited_time"
          }
          ,"weight":1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10000
}
```

**Response**

```
    {
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "max_score" : 1.45973969E12,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "idx0",
      "_type" : "8001",
      "_id" : "null-100-1459739724631",
      "_score" : 1.45973969E12,
      "_routing" : "100",
      "_source" : {
        "visited_time" : 1459739724636
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "idx0",
      "_type" : "8001",
      "_id" : "null-101-1459708570522",
      "_score" : 1.45970862E12,
      "_routing" : "101",
      "_source" : {
        "visited_time" : 1459708570525
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "idx0",
      "_type" : "8001",
      "_id" : "null-101-1459708599619",
      "_score" : 1.45970862E12,
      "_routing" : "101",
      "_source" : {
        "visited_time" : 1459708599620
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "idx0",
      "_type" : "8001",
      "_id" : "null-100-1459708476386",
      "_score" : 1.45970849E12,
      "_routing" : "100",
      "_source" : {
        "visited_time" : 1459708476387
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "idx0",
      "_type" : "8001",
      "_id" : "null-100-1459708421417",
      "_score" : 1.45970836E12,
      "_routing" : "100",
      "_source" : {
        "visited_time" : 1459708421492
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

I don't know why it returns same document score?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine but I guess the precision of numbers you are dealing with is very high. Score of a document is a `double` precision value and not a `long`. Hence while converting the `long` value to `double`, there is some loss in precision and hence you see some results are out of order. Note that only the second and third results are out of order. I guess there is no easy way to fix this problem unless you are dealing with low precision values.

But there is an easy solution for the specific problem you are trying to solve. You can use [sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) which will not have to deal with the problem described above. Use the query below:

```
{
  "query": {
    // query goes here
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "visited_time": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 10000
}
```

Comment: I am using functions score query with sampler aggregation to match the last document of a user. I tried sorting too but it is also not helps.

I explained why I am trying this query in this link https://jsfiddle.net/6kpoq5zc/1/